# Two port networks - Why are shared Z-parameters not negative?

Tags: circuit-analysis, impedance, passive-networks, mesh-analysis

In basic electronics we learned that to solve a circuit using mesh analysis, the shared impedances had to be negative. For example in the circuit bellow, the system of equations would be:

[image]

$$\begin{pmatrix}
Z_1 + Z_3 & -Z_3\\
-Z_3 & Z_2 + Z_3
\end{pmatrix} \cdot \begin{pmatrix}
I_1 \\ 
I_2
\end{pmatrix} = \begin{pmatrix}
V_1 \\ 
-V_2
\end{pmatrix} $$

(The shared impedance (Z3) is negative).

However , now in our filters class we're learning that even the shared Z-parameters (Z12 and Z31) are positive. For example, the Z-parameter matrix for the cirucit above would be :

$$\begin{pmatrix}
Z_1 + Z_3 & Z_3\\
Z_3 & Z_2 + Z_3
\end{pmatrix}  $$

Can anyone tell me why this is ? Am I missing something ; do Z-parameters mean something different that the impedance matrix in mesh analysis ?

Thank you ,

Liam

(https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Two-port_network#Impedance_parameters_(z-parameters))

Comment: Excuse me, but you have 2 different currents named  I2 - the black one and the blue. Which is the right I2?

Comment: @user287001 Thanks, you're right. I fixed the image

Comment: Different current directions explain your problem. In 2 port equations it's common that the currents are as they were in your original image with black.  For it your "no minus sign" equations are right

Comment: @user287001 Oh ok, so then if in my first equation i2 is negative, it would then be the same as if Z12 and Z21 are positive